# React-day-picker disabledDays before after and array

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

So im trying to disable days in react-day-picker with before after and array parameters.

This will only disable before and after

```
    disabledDays={[
      {after:moment().add(1, 'months').toDate()},
      {before:moment().toDate()},
      {bannedDates}
      ]}
```

This will disable the array days so i know bannedDates work

```
        disabledDays={
      bannedDates
      }
```

dates are in format

```
0: Mon Mar 04 2019 16:33:09 GMT+0100 (centraleuropeisk normaltid) {}
```

How can i get all three parameters to work at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just push `{before: ..., after: ...}` to `bannedDates`.

This way:

```
let bannedDates = [...];
bannedDates.push({
    after:moment().add(1, 'months').toDate(),
    before:moment().toDate()
});
```

Then `disabledDays = bannedDates`

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j9klolz89)